# Are there any published coding style guidelines for SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, coding-style

Often I will end up with very complex SQL statements and I wondered if there was style guideline out there that dictates a common way of laying various aspects of a query out.

I am look for something descriptive along the lines of [Python's PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) or [Zend Frameworks guidelines](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.html) and not code by example.

Most of my queries are written for MySQL.

So do you know of a universal style guide? Perhaps you have written one yourself. Please share your guidelines.

Comment: @JNK I have read through most of that question before asking mine. It is not actually what I am looking for. I am after a proper published style guide that the rest of the development team and I can all adopt. This is why I mentioned something along the lines of PEP8.

Comment: @Treffynnon - The last section is what made me link to that question - `Perhaps you have written one yourself. Please share your guidelines.`

Comment: @JNK Fair enough. However that question has a list of examples attached to it and not really descriptive guidelines like the ones I have linked to in my question.

Comment: @Treffynnon - Well I can't remove my vote to close, but if others disagree with me then it won't be an issue :)

Comment: @JNK the possible dupe link is also useful for others who might come across this question as well :-) I probably should have included a link to it in my question!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Since asking this question I have written a public SQL style guide that is compatible with Joe Celko's SQL Programming Style book under the Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike licence.

It is available over at [www.sqlstyle.guide](http://www.sqlstyle.guide/) or as [markdown directly from the GitHub repo](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/treffynnon/sqlstyle.guide/gh-pages/_includes/sqlstyle.guide.md).

Comment: Awesome! (And more characters for SO.)

Answer (score 7):

Here are some SQL programming guidelines and best practices we collected:

- Do not use SELECT * in your queries.
- Always use table aliases when your SQL statement involves more than one source.
- Use the more readable ANSI-Standard Join clauses instead of the old style joins.
- Do not use column numbers in the ORDER BY clause.
- Always use a column list in your INSERT statements.
- Don't ever use double quotes in your T-SQL code.
- Do not prefix your stored procedure names with “sp_”.
- Always use a SQL formatter to format your SQL like [Instant SQL Formatter](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm) (free and online)

You can check detailed explanation of those best practices in [this blog post](http://www.dpriver.com/blog/2011/09/27/a-list-of-sql-best-practices/).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question that was asked.

Answer (score 5):

Two guides I know of are [Joe Celko's SQL Programming Style](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0120887975) and the venerable [Code Complete](http://www.cc2e.com/%20Code%20Complete).

There's also the [SQL-92 standard](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt). It doesn't contain a style section, but you might consider it's style to be implicitly canonical.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL has a short description of their more or less strict rules:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/coding-style.html

Most common codingstyle for MySQL by Simon Holywell:

http://www.sqlstyle.guide/

See also this question:
[Is there a naming convention for MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899200/is-there-a-naming-convention-for-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

Kickstarter [has a style guide here](https://gist.github.com/fredbenenson/7bb92718e19138c20591#file-kickstarter_sql_style_guide-md). I have a modified version of that for people who prefer lowercase SQL and [Celko's "river"](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/formatting-sql-code-part-second/).

[My style guide is here](https://gist.github.com/mattmc3/38a85e6a4ca1093816c08d4815fbebfb). Here is a sample:

```
-- basic select example
select p.Name as ProductName
     , p.ProductNumber
     , pm.Name as ProductModelName
     , p.Color
     , p.ListPrice
  from Production.Product as p
  join Production.ProductModel as pm
    on p.ProductModelID = pm.ProductModelID
 where p.Color in ('Blue', 'Red')
   and p.ListPrice < 800.00
   and pm.Name like '%frame%'
 order by p.Name

-- basic insert example
insert into Sales.Currency (
    CurrencyCode
    ,Name
    ,ModifiedDate
)
values (
    'XBT'
    ,'Bitcoin'
    ,getutcdate()
)

-- basic update example
update p
   set p.ListPrice = p.ListPrice * 1.05
     , p.ModifiedDate = getutcdate()
  from Production.Product as p
 where p.SellEndDate is null
   and p.SellStartDate is not null

-- basic delete example
delete cc
  from Sales.CreditCard as cc
 where cc.ExpYear < '2003'
   and cc.ModifiedDate < dateadd(year, -1, getutcdate())
```

Comment: For someone who likes to use tabs to indent, I don't think I can achieve the column of whitespace between keywords and column names. I do appreciate your usage of leading commas though, I love leading commas.

Comment: @ADJenks This post is my first exposure to leading commas. I am instantly (I think) seeing the benefit. I can't tell you how many times I've modified code and forgotten to either a) strip away a comma prior to the next keyword or b) add a comma in. I imagine this will save me many headaches in the future. Much like reversing logical comparisons: `if ('haley' == $firstName)` Looks strange, but protects against accidentally assigning instead of comparing: `if ('haley' = $firstName)`, as this will throw an error.

Comment: @elbowlobstercowstand I love those too, they are often called Yoda conditions.

Comment: @ADJenks Ahh! Quite clever! A lot from you, I am learning. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about getting your team to use a tool with built in formatting capabilities?Toad for MySql has this. Its not going be a guide as such but a least will bring some consistency.

Comment: This might be a possibility but we have people on MacOS, Linux and Windows so it would need to be cross platform. Some of us need the editing abilities/short cuts that Vim provides as well. But definitely an alternative as many of us currently use SQLYog (under WINE in some cases).