# Is there a naming convention for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, naming-conventions, mysql-workbench

Here's how I do it:

1. Table names are lower case, use underscores to separate words, and are singular (e.g. `foo`, `foo_bar`, etc.
2. I generally (not always) have an auto increment PK. I use the following convention: `tablename_id` (e.g. `foo_id`, `foo_bar_id`, etc.).
3. When a table contains a column that is a foreign key, I just copy the column name of that key from whatever table it came from. For example, say table `foo_bar` has the FK `foo_id` (where `foo_id` is the PK of `foo`).
4. When defining FKs to enforce referential integrity, I use the following: `tablename_fk_columnname` (e.g. furthering example 3, it would be `foo_bar_foo_id`). Since this is a table name/column name combination, it is guaranteed to be unique within the database.
5. I order the columns like this: PKs, FKs, then the rest of columns alphabetically

Is there a better, more standard way to do this?

Comment: Is it wrong to use for auto increment PK just "id"? Why? The name of the column have meaning only in the context of the table. So I have one "id" in every table, and may have many id_<table_name> for FK.

Comment: @Zbyszek I think the simplest reason against that is simply for consistency/simplicity. Rather than having `id_tableB` => *oh no* **different-named column** `id`, the consistency of `id_tableB` => `id_tableB` just looks neater... or as OP does it: `foo_id` => `foo_id` rather than `foo_id` => `id`

Comment: This is a great method. I use almost the same, but for table names, I use plural for "root" table and singular for dependencies. Eg: companies and company_sector.

Comment: "Table names (...) are singular" that would be an instant fail in computer engineering db class. Not because of naming conventions, but because "tables" are a group of something. If it's single, it indicates bad design.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

I would say that first and foremost: be consistent.

I reckon you are almost there with the conventions that you have outlined in your question. A couple of comments though:

Points 1 and 2 are good I reckon.

Point 3 - sadly this is not always possible. Think about how you would cope with a single table `foo_bar` that has columns `foo_id` and `another_foo_id` both of which reference the `foo` table `foo_id` column. You might want to consider how to deal with this. This is a bit of a corner case though!

Point 4 - Similar to Point 3. You may want to introduce a number at the end of the foreign key name to cater for having more than one referencing column.

Point 5 - I would avoid this. It provides you with little and will become a headache when you want to add or remove columns from a table at a later date.

Some other points are:

**Index Naming Conventions**

You may wish to introduce a naming convention for indexes - this will be a great help for any database metadata work that you might want to carry out. For example you might just want to call an index `foo_bar_idx1` or `foo_idx1` - totally up to you but worth considering.

**Singular vs Plural Column Names**

It might be a good idea to address the thorny issue of plural vs single in your column names as well as your table name(s). This subject often causes [big debates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338156/table-naming-dilemma-singular-vs-plural-names) in the DB community. I would stick with singular forms for both table names and columns. There. I've said it.

The main thing here is of course consistency!

Comment: What would be better than point 5? Why it could become a headache?

Comment: To follow up, i found this verry helpful for those who will come here later: https://launchbylunch.com/posts/2014/Feb/16/sql-naming-conventions/#naming-conventions

Comment: I'm having trouble finding a good "scheme" for naming my tables which hold objects of models consisting of two names (DocumentChapter, DocumentVersion, DocumentType etc.). For example for DocumentType i could name it `documenttype` or `document_type`. I would prefer the latter one, but most of the time i have a many to many relationship and i need a table looking like `document_document_type`. Any suggestions how to handle this?

Comment: @rsb2097 Re: point 5 - After adding one column (to the end) the order could become invalid. You shouldn't add any constraint that requires re-ordering the columns as that's an unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 27):

Consistency is the key to any naming standard. As long as it's logical and consistent, you're 99% there.

The standard itself is very much personal preference - so if you like your standard, then run with it.

To answer your question outright - no, MySQL doesn't have a preferred naming convention/standard, so rolling your own is fine (and yours seems logical).

Answer (score 20):

MySQL has a short description of their more or less strict rules:

[https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/coding-style.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20220928071658/https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/coding-style.html)

The most common codingstyle for MySQL by Simon Holywell:

https://www.sqlstyle.guide/

See also this question:

[Are there any published coding style guidelines for SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951245/are-there-any-published-coding-style-guidelines-for-sql/40134564#40134564)

Comment: This is a good reference. sqlstyle.guide has a very comprehensive set of guidelines that cover just about any case.

Answer (score 5):

Thankfully, PHP developers aren't "Camel case bigots" like some development communities I know.

Your conventions sound fine.

Just so long as they're a) simple, and b) consistent - I don't see any problems :)

PS:
Personally, I think 5) is overkill...

Comment: Far from being bigots, camel case is actually frowned upon by many of the DB community because some of the RDBMS' are case insensitive to the point where they will strip cases (or change everything to upper case) so things get really ugly really quickly.

Comment: I like the irony of MySQL users disliking CamelCase and the name of the product we use: MySQL, written in CamelCase

Comment: @DBX12 To be pedantic, that's PascalCase, not camelCase, but your point still stands.

Answer (score 5):

**Simple Answer:** NO

Well, at least a naming convention as such encouraged by Oracle or community, no, however, basically you have to be aware of following the rules and limits for identifiers, such as indicated in MySQL documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html

About the naming convention you follow, I think it is ok, just the number 5 is a little bit unnecesary, I think most visual tools for managing databases offer a option for sorting column names (I use DBeaver, and it have it), so if the purpouse is having a nice visual presentation of your table you can use this option I mention.

By personal experience, I would recommed this:

- **Use lower case**. This almost ensures interoperability when you migrate your databases from one server to another. Sometimes the `lower_case_table_names` is not correctly configured and your server start throwing errors just by simply unrecognizing your camelCase or PascalCase standard (case sensitivity problem).
- **Short names**. Simple and clear. The most easy and fast is identify your table or columns, the better. Trust me, when you make a lot of different queries in a short amount of time is better having all simple to write (and read).
- **Avoid prefixes**. Unless you are using the same database for tables of different applications, don't use prefixes. This only add more verbosity to your queries. There are situations when this could be useful, for example, when you want to indentify primary keys and foreign keys, that usually table names are used as prefix for id columns.
- **Use underscores for separating words**. If you still want to use more than one word for naming a table, column, etc., so use underscores for *separating_the_words*, this helps for legibility (your eyes and your stressed brain are going to thank you).
- **Be consistent**. Once you have your own standard, follow it. Don´t be the person that create the rules and is the first who breaking them, that is shameful.

And what about the "Plural vs Singular" naming? Well, this is most a situation of personal preferences. In my case I try to use plural names for tables because I think a table as a collection of elements or a package containig elements, so a plural name make sense for me; and singular names for columns because I see columns as attributes that describe singularly to those table elements.

Answer (score 1):

Consistency is what everyone strongly suggest, the rest is upto you as long as it works.

For beginners its easy to get carried away and we name whatever we want at that time. This make sense at that point but a headache later.

`foo` `foobar` or `foo_bar` is great.
We name our table straight forward as much as possible and only use underscore if they are two different words. `studentregistration` to `student_registration`

like @Zbyszek says, having a simple `id` is more than enough for the auto-increment. The simplier the better. Why do you need `foo_id`? We had the same problem early on, we named all our columns with the table prefix. like `foo_id`, `foo_name`, `foo_age`. We dropped the tablename now and kept only the col as short as possible.

Since we are using just an id for PK we will be using `foo_bar_fk` (tablename is unique, folowed by the unique PK, followed by the `_fk`) as foreign key. We don't add `id` to the col name because it is said that the name 'id' is always the PK of the given table. So we have just the tablename and the `_fk` at the end.

For constrains we remove all underscores and join with camelCase (tablename + Colname + Fk) `foobarUsernameFk` (for username_fk col). It's just a way we are following. We keep a documentation for every names structures.

When keeping the col name short, we should also keep an eye on the RESTRICTED names.

```
+------------------------------------+
|               foobar               |
+------------------------------------+
| id (PK for the current table)      |
| username_fk (PK of username table) |
| location (other column)            |
| tel (other column)                 |
+------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

as @fabrizio-valencia said use lower case. in windows if you export mysql database (phpmyadmin) the tables name will converted to lower case and this lead to all sort of
problems.
see [Are table names in MySQL case sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134006/are-table-names-in-mysql-case-sensitive)