# Create database with dasherized name from mysql CLI

Tags: mysql, database, command-line

When I use the MySQL client to create database, if I type below command:

```
create database nice-day;
```

Then it tells me that:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-day' at line 1
```

But when I use **phpAdmin** tool, I can create the database named nice-day. What is the problem?

Comment: you should not use - instead use _

see the link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899200/is-there-a-naming-convention-for-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-` character is not considered to be part of an identifier in SQL, so the database name must be quoted:

```
CREATE DATABASE `nice-day`
```

In general, though, it is advisable to use underscores (`_`) instead of dashes in database names to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please use backticks "`" (the key before the 1 on a standard US 101 keyboard).

as per http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html

```
    The identifier quote character is the backtick (“`”):
```