# Laravel unique validation issue

Tags: php, validation, laravel, unique, eloquent

I try to make a unique validation the settings of my website but this doesn't work :

In my controller :

```
$rules = array(
    'username' => 'required|unique:User,username,10',
    'email'    => 'required|email|unique:User,email,10',
    'language' => 'required|in:fr,en',
);
```

My model:

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_user';
    protected $table = 'user';

}
```

The problem is:

My Validator `Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules, $messages);` fails, it says that this username and email already exist.

Comment: **What** doesn't work?

Comment: My Validator `Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules, $messages);` fails, it says that this username and email already exist.

Comment: Are `username` and `email` defined as unique in the DB? And with the last parameter '10' you ignore the `id_user` 10. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disagree** with the answer to your own question:

> "Laravel is not done to search in a custom column".

This is not true.

*To be precise: There is nothing bad in using a Plugin...*

---

See the important part of a migration file (app/database/migrations):

```
   // creates a DB-table named 'users'
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $t) {
        $t->increments('id');
        $t->timestamps();
        // ... Here a unique field
        $t->string('user_email_one', 255)->unique();
        // ...
    });
```

And the relevant validation rules in the `UserController`:

```
     $rules = array(
        'user_email_one' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        // ...
     );
```

And Laravel is doing its job.

---

**With `unique:` you have to call the DB-table name, not the model name.**

*BTW: the plugin you've chosen does this...*

[The Laravel docs about validation](http://laravel.com/docs/validation):

> **unique:table,column,except,idColumn**
>
> The field under validation must be unique on a given database table.
>
> If the column option is not specified, the field name will be used.

---

Just as an interesting info about naming a mySQL table `'User'`, `'user'` or `'users'`, which could have caused your error. Visit this question:

[Is there a naming convention for MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899200/is-there-a-naming-convention-for-mysql) asked by [StackOverflowNewbie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/253976/stackoverflownewbie), answered by [Tom Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/966491/tom-mac) (highest vote & accepted answer)

Answer (score 0):

Laravel is not done to search in a custom column.

So I have installed this plugin https://github.com/felixkiss/uniquewith-validator who did the job very well:

```
$rules = array(
    'username' => 'required|alpha_dash|unique_with:user,username,10 = id_user',
    'email'    => 'required|email|unique_with:user,email,10 = id_user',
    'language' => 'required|in:fr,en',
);
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I want, but I forgot to make `username` and `email` unique on my database...