# Having issues with a MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

The code below is used to retrieve some simple data from a MySQL table named people's names.

```
<?php
$user = "root"; //Connection to DB  
$pass = "";
$db = "testdb";
$link = new mysqli('localhost' , $user , $pass, $db) or die("unable to connect");

$query = "select * from  people's names";
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)){

    echo "It Worked!";

} else {

    echo "it failed!";  

}
?>
```

I checked the code over and over again and have searched every corner of the internet to find an answer but can't seem to prevent the inevitable "it failed!"
message when I load the page. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks -Dylan.

Comment: You need to use backticks on the table name `SELECT * FROM \`people's names\``

Comment: `echo "it failed!";` will never help you debug code. Use error reporting. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Thank you Tristian for the help. It works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`people's names` is not a valid table name. That's likely your issue, assuming your connection parameters are correct.

Answer (score 4):

In Mysql `'` is a special character you need to escape it in your query. I would avoid such in table names or escape it with back ticks.

A good question on naming conventions for mysql [Is there a naming convention for MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899200/is-there-a-naming-convention-for-mysql)

[MySql Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html)

Answer (score 1):

Adding to wogsland and Pox their answers.

I would say names is already plural, so you don't need to pluralize people. So a good table name could be

```
people_names
```

depending on other conventions you could also use

```
peopleNames
```