# Writing Data into sql table/ http error 500

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to write data into MySQL table but continue to get an 'HTTP error 500' page when I click submit. I don't think it has anything to do with the form but here is the code im using:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="rma.php">
    <p>
    Start Date:<br />
    <input type="date" name="datecomp"><br /><br />
    <select name="action">
      <option value="record">Record New Entry</option>
      <option value="search">Search for Existing</option>
    </select><br />
    <br />
    Status:<br />
    <select name="status">
      <option value="Complete">Complete</option>
      <option value="Follow Up">Follow Up</option>
    </select><br />
    Last Name/Last 4:</br>
    <input type="text" name="nameLast4" placeholder="last name, last 4 digits of social"></br>
    Device/s:</br>
    <input type="text" name="device" placeholder="(multiple separated by commas)"></br>
    Device Serial Number/s:</br>
    <input type="tel" name="serial" placeholder="..."></br>
    New Serial Number:</br>
    <input type="text" name="newser" placeholder="..."><br /><br />
    Flagged:</br>
    <input type="radio" name="flag" value="yes">&nbspYes&nbsp<input type="radio" name="flag" value="no">&nbspNo&nbsp</br><br />
    Warranty Expired:</br>
    <input type="radio" name="warranty" value="yes">&nbspYes&nbsp<input type="radio" name="warranty" value="no">&nbspNo&nbsp</br><br />
    Date Returned to Vendor:</br>
    <input type="date" name="returnDate"><br /><br />
    UPS Tracking:<br />
    <input type="tel" name="ups" placeholder="..."></br><br />
    RMA Form Upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"><br /><br />
    RMA Number:<br />
    <input type="text" name="RMA_#" placeholder="..."><br />
    <br />
    Date Completed:<br />
    <input type="date" name="datecomp"><br /><br />
    E.T.A. (If Available):<br />
    <input type="date" name="eta"><br /><br />
    Initials<br />
    <input type="text" name="init"><br />

    <textarea name="notes" cols="30" rows="5" placeholder="Optional Notes..."></textarea>
    </br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">&nbsp<input type="reset" value="Clear Form">&nbsp
    </p>
</form>
```

And then the PHP....

```
<?php
$action = $_POST['action'];
$status = $_POST['status'];
$name = $_POST['nameLast4'];
$dev = $_POST['device'];
$serial = $_POST['serial'];
$rmanum = $_POST['RMA_#'];
$flag = $_POST['flag'];
$ups = $_POST['ups'];
$warr = $_POST['warranty'];
$returndate = $_POST['returnDate'];
$newser = $_POST['newser'];
$eta = $_POST['eta'];
$rmaform = $_POST['fileToUpload'];
$datestart = $_POST['startdate'];
$datecomp = $_POST['datecomp'];
$init = $_POST['init'];
$comments = $_POST['notes'];


$servername = "localhost";
$username = "kylezeio_admin";
$password = "********";
$dbname = "kylezeio_RMA";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
if ($action === "record"){
$sql = "INSERT INTO `kylezeio_RMA`.`RMA Records` (`ID`, `Complete/Follow up`, `Name/Last4`, `Device`, `Serial Number`, `RMA Number`, `Flagged`, `UPS Tracking`, `Warranty Expired`, `Date Returned`, `New Serial Number`, `E.T.A. (if available)`, `Date Completed`, `Date Started`, `Initials`, `Comments`) VALUES (NULL, $status, $name, $dev, $serial, $rmanum, $flag, $ups, $warr, $returndate, $newser, $eta, $datecomp, $datestart, $init, $comments);";
}
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();        

?>
```

You can also view the page @ http://kylejoeckel.com/RMA%20Form.html

Thanks in advance...

**EDIT:**

I was missing a semicolon so i believe that that is why i got the 500 error, now i am getting this:

Error: INSERT INTO `kylezeio_RMA`.`RMA Records` (`ID`, `Complete/Follow up`, `Name/Last4`, `Device`, `Serial Number`, `RMA Number`, `Flagged`, `UPS Tracking`, `Warranty Expired`, `Date Returned`, `New Serial Number`, `E.T.A. (if available)`, `Date Completed`, `Date Started`, `Initials`, `Comments`) VALUES (NULL, Complete, joeckel,9999, cmdr, 589437609287, l654651, yes, 1z8e983756987, no, 2016-11-21, 356928679, 2016-11-17, 2016-11-08, , hg, test);
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' hg, test)' at line 1

but i dont know what syntax error it would be refering to.

Comment: Do you really have column names in your table with slashes and spaces in them?

Comment: yes i do... im new to using mySQL and databases in general, is that not typically accepted?

Comment: Recommended to avoid that, eg: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899200/is-there-a-naming-convention-for-mysql

Comment: ok, thanks, but this isn't hat is causing my error is it?

Comment: I bet you get the 500 error even without sending your form to that php page. Try submitting it into whatever void instead, like a blank html page, so you can check that off the debug list. What's happening in your `.htaccess`, a more likely culprit?

Comment: BTW what you have there is wide open for SQL injections. Consider using prepared statements, or at the very least `mysqli_real_escape_string()` all your user input.

Comment: @KyleMathewJoeckel - honestly, difficult to tell because your code is naive - see other comments with advice and make it easy on yourself and others by writing clean code when you can. To solve, dump $sql and try running the generated query in phpMyAdmin or whatever and see if the error message helps you more.

Comment: Your syntax error is with all those unquoted strings, you need to quote strings that go into a SQL statement.

Comment: Strings must be quoted to work.  Values (whether strings or not) must be parametized to be secure.

Comment: You really should read this one before using any of your code in a production environment, "How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: ok that makes sense thanks @MarkusAO

Comment: Quotes your strings need them, here `$status, $name, $dev, $serial, $rmanum, $flag, $ups, $warr, $returndate, $newser, $eta, $datecomp, $datestart, $init, $comments`. Use parameterized queries so you also close your SQL injection. To see the exact cause of the 500 check your error logs..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give you an exact answer I would need to see your table create statement.
But let's give it a go anyways. You're simply missing quotes around strings.

Give this a try.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `kylezeio_RMA`.`RMA Records` (`ID`, `Complete/Follow up`, `Name/Last4`, `Device`, `Serial Number`, `RMA Number`, `Flagged`, `UPS Tracking`, `Warranty Expired`, `Date Returned`, `New Serial Number`, `E.T.A. (if available)`, `Date Completed`, `Date Started`, `Initials`, `Comments`) 
VALUES 
(NULL, $status, $name, $dev, $serial, $rmanum, $flag, $ups, $warr, $returndate, $newser, $eta, $datecomp, $datestart, '$init', '$comments');";
```

Comment: What did you quote?

Comment: Just guessing but comments is most likely a string. Strings need single quotations around them in an insert statement.

Comment: Yea, almost all of them need quotes.

Comment: @JackDaniels Thank you for just answering my question and not trying to make me feel like an idiot, the quotes is what I needed, much appreciated!

Comment: Others that suggested quote thank you as well but I am very very new to sql and php so I really needed it drawn out... btw I put the quotes around every variable just to be safe and it is working.